Не работает Телеграм бота
Написал ТГ бота, работает корректно. Однако пытаюсь запустить его через терминал Убунту и автоматизировать так, чтобы работал без моего прямого участия. По итогу он выводит, что бот запущен, но при прямом взаимодействие с ботом крашится выдавая рандомную ошибку, при перезапуске бота он меняет ошибку:
main.service - My Telegram Bot Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/main.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-12-25 08:10:46 UTC; 16s ago
   Main PID: 16922 (python3)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 9033)
     Memory: 27.5M (peak: 27.9M)
        CPU: 314ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/main.service
             └─16922 /home/ubuntu/Downloads/Bot/path/to/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/Downloads/Bot/main.py

Dec 25 08:10:58 ubuntu python3[16922]:              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Dec 25 08:10:58 ubuntu python3[16922]:   File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/Bot/main.py", line 86, in handle_query
Dec 25 08:10:58 ubuntu python3[16922]:     show_domain_list(chat_id)  # Показать список доменов
Dec 25 08:10:58 ubuntu python3[16922]:     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Dec 25 08:10:58 ubuntu python3[16922]:   File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/Bot/main.py", line 109, in show_domain_list
Dec 25 08:10:58 ubuntu python3[16922]:     sorted_domains = get_sorted_domains()
Dec 25 08:10:58 ubuntu python3[16922]:                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Dec 25 08:10:58 ubuntu python3[16922]:   File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/Bot/database_function.py"
Dec 25 08:10:58 ubuntu python3[16922]:     cursor.execute('SELECT domain, finished_at, ssl_certificate_info, ssl_created_at, ssl_finished_at FROM domains ORDER BY finished_at ASC>
Dec 25 08:10:58 ubuntu python3[16922]: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: domains



файл с базой данных не в текущем каталоге?

все в одном каталоге

возможно. но в том каталоге, который является у вас текущим при ручном запуске, в файле базы данных есть таблица, а при запуске как демона - в (вероятно) другом текущем каталоге в файле базы данных таблицы нет. разные каталоги - разные файлы с базой данных. логично?

Проблема оказалась в том, что мы не указали среду и рабочую директорию:P
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/Downloads/Bot
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/Downloads/Bot/path/to/venv/bin"
Спасибо за помощь!
